# Trying to change 2D sprite colors with a list and nothing renders

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a new to programming and I'm trying to change the sprite color of a gameObject using a list that contain colors in Unity. When I spawn a new object each time, the inspector shows a different color for the object (which seems to show that the code works) but nothing render in the scene when the game is on. It's like the code works but is missing something.

Here's the code

```
[SerializeField] private List<Color> _listeCouleurs = new List<Color>();

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    SpriteRenderer spriteRender = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

        Color c = _listeCouleurs[Random.Range(0, _listeCouleurs.Count)];
        _listeCouleurs.Add(spriteRender.color);
        spriteRender.color = c;

}
```

Hope someone can help me cause I don't see any solution to this and there's nothing on the internet that can help me fix this bug.

Comment: Does the sprite show/render in the editor?

Comment: yes can you see the sprite at all? Maybe it is offscreen or rotated in a way so you can't see it? Can you see it in the SceneView?

Comment: Not at all, I can't see nothing in the scene but the editor show that the sprite color has one of the color from the list.

Comment: Also without the code, the sprite just spawn on the scene like I want so I know that is not offscreen or a rotation problem

Answer (score 0):

When you added colors to the list with the "eyedropper", the transparency is set to 0, set it to opaque (255 in the RGB range, 1 in [Color.a](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color-a.html) scale) and everything will be visible:

```cs
Color c = _listeCouleurs[Random.Range(0, _listeCouleurs.Count)];
c.a = 1.0f;

_listeCouleurs.Add(spriteRender.color);
spriteRender.color = c;
```